# Qt code port to marmalade

Tags: windows, qt, mingw, porting, marmalade

I know Marmalade is very good for c++ code porting but I would like to know how could it possible to port my Qt code to marmalade?

Can anyone tell how simple "hello world" Qt-application could  be ported to marmalade?

I have setup every thing for marmalade on Windows machine. Also I have already setup Qt.

Please, share any kind of info or tutorials here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible with IwGx and its subcomponents and probably not with s3e. You can try using IwUI, but I don't think it will work.

Another thing, Qt doesn't support all the platforms Marmalade does, so you won't reach the clients you might want to get to.

I found this on the marmalade forum, which might be useful.
http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/ru/node/57339

Hope it helps!